# Why does printing someArray.insert() show up as "none" and how do I fix it?

Tags: python

Why is `none` coming up with my code and how can i fix it?

My code is:

```
stores=["meijer", "walmart", "kroger", "trader joes", "dollar general"]
print str(stores.insert(3, "aldi"))+("\nAldi is now in the list:\n")+str((stores))
```

It outputs this :

```
None
Aldi is now in the list:
['meijer', 'walmart', 'kroger', 'aldi', 'kohls', 'dollar general']
```

Comment: `list.insert` is performed in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: `list.insert` returns `None`

Comment: Is there any way that I can print that in one line without separating list.insert?

Comment: what are you expecting it to output? it is in the list

Comment: The output shouldn't print out "None" and the all code should be in two lines. that's all I want..

Comment: Please Helpp!!!

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but _why_ do you want the code in 2 lines? Readability is important. And why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Why must it be in a single line? Is there some lack of lines available?

Comment: I know its so easy to print it out in 3 lines but its also looks unprofessional in 2 lines but that's what the challenge is. There should be a way to do it....

Comment: Alright I got my answer. But i have one more question

Comment: What does the %s and % does???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* must have a one-liner, here's a way it can be done in Python 2:

```
stores = ["meijer", "walmart", "kroger", "trader joes", "dollar general"]
print stores.insert(3, "aldi") or "\nAldi is now in the list:\n%s" % stores
```

**output**

```
Aldi is now in the list:
['meijer', 'walmart', 'kroger', 'aldi', 'trader joes', 'dollar general']
```

This works because `stores.insert(3, "aldi")` returns `None`, and `None or thing` evaluates to `thing`.

Comment: @Dylan They are an old way of doing string formatting. The `%s` says "insert a string here", the other `%` introduces the object or tuple of objects to insert into the the string containing the `%s`. You can read about it in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). Many people prefer to use the more readable `.format` method instead (but the old way is a little faster, and more compact). And in Python 3 there's also the new way of formatting using f-strings.